# trying to prove $Ax + B\sin(x) = C$ has at least one root ( with Bolzano's theorem )

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I just want to prove that for every choice from real numbers (except $A=0$) the equation above (and below) always has at least one root by using the Intermediate value theorem.

**What I tried**: let

$$f(x) = Ax + B\sin(x) - C$$

We have to prove for any desired value of $A$ or $B$ or $C$, we are able to find a couple of $x$'s such that $f$ changes its sign, in one case becoming positive, in the other one becoming negative. So, trying to make an easy guess, I choose the values $x=\pi$ and $x=2\pi$ because with this choice the term containing $B$ in the function $f$ will vanish:\

- if $x=\pi$ then : $f(\pi) = a\cdot\pi - c$
- if $x=2\pi$ then : $f (2\pi) = a \cdot 2\pi - c$

But now the problem is that even for these two values there are many states that it's really hard to consider. Our knowledge in class was only limited to solving problems with given and fixed values for $A$, $B$, $C$,... and this case is completely new. If anyone has an idea or can  solve this question, I will be happy if they could share it with me. (I apologize for giving little information in the previous question).

Comment: if $C=0$ it's obvious. Otherwise consider $x_k = k\pi$ and note that $f(x_k) = Ak\pi - C$.

Comment: Almost same question asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4813184?noredirect=1) yesterday

Comment: Can the solution not be based on the Intermediate Value Theorem? Do you only want it to be solved by Bolzano's Theorem?

Comment: @ТymaGaidash  Yeah that was mine but unfortunately, it got closed.

Comment: @ShubhavJain in this case No!

Answer (score 0):

It is given that $A \neq 0$. Find a value of $x$ where $Ax-C > \left|B\right|$ and another where $Ax-C < -\left|B\right|$. Apply Bolzano's Theorem between two values of $x$ found for the function $f(x) = Ax + B\sin(x) - C$ by showing that the values of the function have different signs at the two values of $x$, using the range of $\sin(x)$. This will prove the existence of at least one root in the said interval.